# Initializer must be constant

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C but I get an error in the following code.
If I use **radius** in volume I get an error: `error #2069: Initializer must be constant.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI (3.14)

/* Define radius*/
int radius = 10;
float volume = ( 4.0f / (3.0f * PI * radius) );

int main(void){

return 0;
}
```

But when I change radius with an actual number, it compiles just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI (3.14)

/* Define radius*/
int radius = 10;
float volume = ( 4.0f / (3.0f * PI * 10) );

int main(void){

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to make the first version work?

Comment: Because *Initializer must be constant*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C you cannot initialize global variables with non-constant expressions.

**C99 Standard: Section 6.7.8:**

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

In your example, `volume` is a global variable with static storage duration and `radius` is not a constant. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, can i just ask why volume is global variable ant radius is not?

Comment: @intelis, you are confusing terms. `radius` *is* a global variable, but it is not a constant expression.

Comment: @intelis: Both `volume` and `radius` are placed outside any function in the file(*rather TU*), Hence both of them are global and have static storage duration. Both should be initialized with constant expressions. Note that neither of them form constant expressions.

Comment: i dont understand, why volume is not a constant, if it has a value that does not change.i mean, what is the difference between radius and volume in terms of being a constant?

Comment: @intelis: You say `volume` is constant because its value does not change anywhere in the program.For C and your compiler an variable is constant only if it is explicitly declared as constant. For ex: `const int x;` tells the compiler `x` is constant. There is more detail though.As the standard quote says *initializer should be constant expression*, In C(*unlike C++*) `const` declarations do not produce constant expressions. So even with `const int radius = 10;` your code will [not compile](http://ideone.com/LirwjH). In C the  way to produce a constant expression is by using `#define`'s

Answer (score 3):

In C, you can only initialize a variable outside a function with *constant expressions*.  `int radius` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 3):

A *static object* can't be initialized with a non-constant expression. In your example,

```
float volume = ( 4.0f / (3.0f * PI * radius) );
```

`volume` is a global variable and has static duration. So it can't be initialized with a non-constant expression.

However, if `volume` is a local variable then it can be initialized with a non-constant value in C99. So the following is allowed (non-constant initialization) in `C99`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI (3.14)

/* Define radius*/
int radius = 10;

int main(void){
float volume = ( 4.0f / (3.0f * PI * radius) );
return 0;
}
```

But the same is not valid in `C90` in which all initalizers must be constant expressions.

Comment: thanks. so an int is a non-static object in c, while a float is a static? what is the difference?

Comment: No, it's not a`int` vs `float` thing. Global variables have static duration while local variables have automatic duration. In my answer, `volume` is a local variable and `radius`(static object) is a global variable. The *type* of the object doesn't matter, rather where & how they are declared makes the difference.

Answer (score 1):

A constant in this regard is something without a memory address. `radius` has a memory address, so it cannot be used for the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It is just C, not C++, so `radius` must be constant, but if you want it as a variable.
Define `volume` in `main()` as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI (3.14)

/* Define radius*/
int radius = 10;
int main(void){
float volume = ( 4.0f / (3.0f * PI * radius) );
return 0;
}
```

Now, the error may vanish.